# applet not loading in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, applet, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to load an applet through a webapp in tomcat. I have my my class files and the applet works if I open the HMTL file with applet in a browser. But if I try to open the same HMTL file through tomcat server it shows `ClassNotFoundException`. I don't understand what I am missing out here.

I have the HMTL file `applet.html` in the root directory of the webapp and have the class files and jar file in student app folder. I have my applet tag as

```
<--applet
  codebase="studentapp/" 
  code="studentapp.class" 
  width="450" height="450" 
  archive="studentapp.jar" />
```

The applet recognizes the class file when I open the `applet.html` file. but when I try to open it through the tomcat server `localhost:8080/student/applet.html`, it shows the exception.

Comment: 1)  `<--applet` should be `<applet` & `"studentapp.jar" />` should be `"studentapp.jar" ></applet>`.  I doubt those changes will fix it but do them and edit the answer with new applet element.  2) what is located in `localhost:8080/student/studentapp/`  - give a directory listing.  3) What is in `studentapp.jar` [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15744935/edit) with the output of `jar -tvf studentapp.jar`

Comment: Did you succeeded to deploy it?

Answer (score 0):

Emm...

> localhost:8080/student/applet.html

I suppose you should place your applet student folder to the Tomcat webapps folder... :S
Anyway, please read carefully [Tomcat deployment specifications](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html) before asking that kind of questions

---

Report if that was useful